# Сгенерировать разметку Avalonia из кода

Tags: c#, avalonia

мне нужно по файлу *.axaml сгенерировать код на C# как это происходит в Visual Studio под капотом во время исполнения программы. Куда копать по этой теме и какие функции использовать? Конечная цель это сделать программу которая сможет модифицировать свои исходники и перекомпилировать себя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Is it possible to load XAML runtime in Avalonia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66989316/12888024)

Перевод:

Установите пакет **Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.Loader** и используйте класс `AvaloniaRuntimeXamlLoader`.

Примеры можно найти по [этой ссылке](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/master/tests/Avalonia.Markup.Xaml.UnitTests/Xaml/BasicTests.cs).